# Abbreviation in system .Net generated code

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions, eventhandler, hungarian-notation

While Microsoft suggests to avoid using abbreviations in code, why do the system generated code of Event Handler contains following line?

```
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Notice that "e" is in abbreviation. Does this rule not apply to Event Handlers?

Comment: That's not really hungarian notation, just an abbreviated name for the `EventArgs` class.

Comment: No, it is actually lower camel case.

Comment: I think I need to rephrase my question now. Talking about Microsoft Naming convention on abbreviations. Does using "e" for EventArgs is violation of rule?

Answer (score 0):

No, its not a Hungarian notation. It just an abbreviated name (as mentioned in comments above)
And you better to read more about Hungarian notations.

> Hungarian notation is an identifier naming convention in computer
>   programming, in which the name of a variable or function indicates its
>   intention or kind.

Ex: `string strName="";`
here you mention the type of variable , as a part of the variable name. But in modern days , its useless due to different reasons.

- You can find the type through the IDE easily, so, no need to mention it on name
- difficult to change the variable type, need to change its name too.

and many more.

Comment: I think I need to rephrase my question now. Talking about Microsoft Naming convention on abbreviations. Does using "e" for EventArgs is violation of rule?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been well-answered above, but I'll throw in my $0.02 on Hungarian Notation.

There is a great article that touches on Hungarian Notation [Here](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/).  It addresses some misconceptions about Hungarian notation, in particular what is it *supposed to be*, as opposed to what it is *often assumed to be.*

The example in the answer from @Hiran is what is is often assumed to be, and Hiran is quite correct:  putting the `str` prefix on `string strName` is redundant with a modern IDE.

The main take-away from the linked article is from this paragraph:

> In Simonyi’s version of Hungarian notation, every variable was prefixed with a lower case tag that indicated the kind of thing that the variable contained.
>
> For example, if the variable name is rwCol, rw is the prefix.
>
> I’m using the word kind on purpose, there, because Simonyi mistakenly used the word type in his paper, and generations of programmers misunderstood what he meant.

I understand that Microsoft's guideline on *not* using Hungarian Notation was more about what it has become (prefixing the variable name with the variable type).

Thus, in the original intent, "Hungarian Notation" could be to use `string pName` (for 'productName') instead of `string name`.

As to the original question, the same declaration in Hungarian Notation might be more like:

```
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs tcArgs)
```

Given that these `EventArgs e` are in the Event Handler, I'm not convinced such notation is particularly useful *in this specific case*.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed insights. I think I need to rephrase my question now. Talking about Microsoft Naming convention on abbreviations. Does using "e" for EventArgs is violation of rule?